# silverlight and wcf security without iis

Tags: .net, silverlight, wcf

If I wanted to call wcf services that were not hosted in iis from a silverlight application.  What would be the best way to secure them?

Comment: You don't need iis to secure WCF services... The security layer is built into the ServiceHost level.  Also, what are you requirements for security)?  Do you need encryption?  Identity?  Message Integrity

Comment: A user logs into my Silverlight application.  Somehow the Silverlight application determines he has valid credentials (maybe via a wcf).  Also messages between silverlight and wcf should be encrypted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Encryption**

This question talks about encryption:

[Other ways to encrypt WCF Connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50684/other-ways-to-encrypt-wcf-connections)

**Authentication**

This MSDN page describes how to set up Username / password authentication:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx

This basically revolves around providing your own implementation of the [UserNamePasswordValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.selectors.usernamepasswordvalidator.aspx) class and hooking that up in configuration.

Comment: Here's a reference that may be of value: http://geekswithblogs.net/SunnyCoder/archive/2009/03/15/username-password-amp-ws-security-with-silverlight.aspx  I have used it with success.